# progressdialog going behind a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have created dialog and it inflates xml which gets updated with the info  .But the progress dialog is shown behind the dialog which pops up .How do I show those progressdialog on top of dialog with inflated xml.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


           dialog();
        }


        public class loadasync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

            ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                super.onPreExecute();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                          progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
                        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        progressDialog.show();
                    }
                });         
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


                         progressDialog.dismiss();   
                    }       
                });
            }
        }   



        public void dialog() {

            dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogxml);

        loadasync loadasyncdata=new loadasync();
        loadasyncdata.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);


            dialog.show();


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see that you are using the setProgressStyle() in your code. That is:

```
 progessDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
```

for instance.

So in your code try the following:

```
 public void run() {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
                    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider : OnPostExecute and onPreExecute are both run on the UI thread, so you can remove the runOnUIThread stuff, just do

```
        protected void onPreExecute() {
          progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
          progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
          progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
          progressDialog.show();
        }
```

and respectively in onPostExecute

```
       protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
          progressDialog.dismiss();   
        }
```

Should maybe be a comment, but the reputation ...